# Create GeoTIFF from raster image and shapefile with extent

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a couple of hundred raster images (TIFF) with a specific file name, like 242_13_1_0.tif. I also have a shapefile with polygons that corresponds to the corners of one of these files. All polygons have an attribute id that could be used to link a specific polygon to a specific file.

I have previously, when I have done something similar, exported the shapefile to some text format and then created a Python script and with Python/GDAL mapped the image to the correct extent and then create a GeoTIFF. But it's a bit time consuming to have to write new specific scripts whenever this problem occurs, so my question is if this could be done more automatically? Like in QGIS?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? What's the problem?

Comment: Well, to be able to create a GeoTIFF, from a "plain" TIFF and the extents that I have in the Shape file. As I described I have an attribute in the shape file that I can use to match to the correct image. So with a Python script and GDAL I have managed to create GeoTIFFs but the question is if this is something this could be done in QGIS or anything like that, so I don't have to write new scripts everytime I have this kind of "problems"

Comment: If you have an image that is not registered in any coordinate reference system, and you want to register it correctly, then you need, in the general case, more than the 4 corners of the extent of the shapefile. Typically more than 8 points are required to do a full georeference. Or maybe I still do not understand...

Comment: The image is not a geograhpical image, but its corners matches the polygons in the Shape file. The Shape file is sort of a overview image of all the maps and every polygon has a ID that corresponds to a filename. So if I match the correct polygon to the correct raster image, with the ID and the file name,  then I can set the set the corners of the image and create a GeoTIFF. This is what I have done in my Python script but I was thiking if this could be done in QGIS. No need to re-invent the wheel over and over again.